# In what order do events fire when added to buttons, in Flash?

Tags: flash, actionscript-3, flash-cs5

If I do this:

```
    myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doThingA);
    myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doThingB);
```

Is there any guarantee that when the user clicks the button the events will be fired in some sequence, and if so, what's the order? Or does the first event just get deleted?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

They are called in the order registered, so in your example `doThingA` will be called before `doThingB` as long as they have the same priority.

To alter which is triggered first then simply add a seperate priority for each listener. The listener with the highest priority will be triggered first, then the one with the lower priority.

```
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doThingA, false, 0); // second
myButton.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, doThingB, false, 1); // first
```

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

They both have a default priority of zero (`priority:int = 0` from arguments given to [addEventListener](http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/events/IEventDispatcher.html?filter_flash=cs5&filter_flashplayer=10.2&filter_air=2.6#addEventListener%28%29)) so the sequence is the order they are added.

To change the order after this you will need to re-register the listener.

Another way would be to make helper functions that push the multiple listeners to a list and give each one a name. Then add the events within that helper function.

```
myButton.addEventListenerHelper(TypeA, MouseEvent.CLICK, doThingA, false, 0); 
myButton.addEventListenerHelper(TypeB, MouseEvent.CLICK, doThingB, false, 1); 
// And then remove by making some helper function to iterate the list for the 
// given listener
myButton.removeEventListenerHelper(TypeA, MouseEvent.CLICK);
```